# Sending http/https requests to a specific server behind router

Tags: windows, router, hyper-v, http, https

Let me start by saying that I am fairly new to Hyper-V and networking.

In my current setup I have 3 separate servers running Windows Datacenter 2022, one of which is running a Hyper-V VM. I have given them all static IP's `192.168.2.2`, `192.168.2.3`, and `192.168.2.4`. I also have 3 website addresses, we'll call them `example1.com`, `example2.com`, and `example3.com`. These servers are all hardwired into my TP-Link router, which is setup to forward any incoming requests on ports 80/443 to my first server (`192.168.2.2`). This has worked well for me up until now, because the websites I have are all hosted on this machine.

What I am trying to do is host `example1.com`/`example2.com` on the first server (`192.168.2.2`), and then host example3.com on another server, let's say, `192.168.2.3`.

How can I push web traffic that comes from `example3.com` to `192.168.2.3`, without affecting `example1.com`/`example2.com`? To make it just a bit harder, the server `192.168.2.3` is running a Hyper-V VM of Ubuntu Server, which is where the website lives.

Let me know if I could provide anymore information, or I am not being clear as to what I am trying to do. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't know enough about IIS to get into the details, but you're looking at running a reverse proxy on one system, then using that to route trafifc for a hostname to the appropriate server

Comment: A (too?) trivial solution would be to assign different ports to the servers and use [port-forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on the router. Otherwise see for example [Setup IIS with URL Rewrite as a reverse proxy for real world apps](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world/ba-p/846222).

Comment: Thank you both for your replies! You were correct, the reverse proxy server in IIS worked perfectly to point traffic to correct server. However, I still need to figure out how to direct that traffic into Hyper-V. Any ideas?

Comment: The answer by Tiger Li [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/2731dfe3-f1bc-4d2a-8437-23b2d426b7b0/how-to-route-from-public-ip-to-web-server-in-hyperv-vm-which-uses-rras-for-nat?forum=winserverPN) is pretty old, but goes through the various steps of configuring a Hyper-V host to push network traffic to a VM via NAT. If the VM already has internet connectivity, then you can probably start at step E and work your way down.